# Having trouble with Jquery/JSON

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json

I'm trying to iterate through a JSON response that's generated from my code-behind. The string that my code is returning is:

```
[{"Symbol":"^GDAXI","Last":"6787.49","Change":"+38.73"},{"Symbol":"^FTSE","Last":"5894.65","Change":"+18.72"}]
```

I'm trying to iterate through this using:

```
<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function (){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Stocks.asmx/GetQuote",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (stocks) {
                $(stocks).each(function (index) {
                    $('#stocks').append("<li>" + this.Symbol + "</li>");
                });                    
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
<p>
    <ul id="stocks"></ul>
</p>
</asp:Content>
```

All I'm getting is an li item with 'undefined'.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Does your ASMX service defined to return JSON and not XML?

Comment: Which Symbol do you want? I do not see a Symbol defined in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That `.each()` doesn't look right.

Try:

```
$(stocks).each(function (index, value) {
    $('#stocks').append("<li>" + value.Symbol + "</li>");
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but no luck :-)

I realised I'm supposed to use:

$.each(stocks, function(stock) {
  $('#stocks').append("<li>" + stock.Symbol + "</li>");
});

but that's not working either..

Comment: Can you inspect the stocks object to see if it looks as expected? `console.log(stocks)`

Comment: Just had a look at it seems the stock value is the entire json string.. something very wrong with that :-S

Comment: So it's not being parsed into an Object?

Comment: Have you tried using `jQuery.getJSON()` instead of `.ajax()`?

Comment: I'll look into it now. At least I've narrowed down the problem.. my JSON response isn't generating correctly. The jquery is looping fine on a hard coded string.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: FYI, the jQuery AJAX method wont automatically parse JSON responses into JavaScript Objects so you have to do that yourself. That's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The callback passed to 'each' receives two arguments. You got to write something like this:

```
$(stocks).each(function(index, data){ console.log(data.Symbol); });
```